# Common Compression method for audio,video and images in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, compression, image-compression

I'm using the react-native-compression package for compressing the files, but while using it I'm having an error.

[image: error message]

and here is the code where I'm adding the Image compressor:

[image: code where using compressors]

I'm getting the file URL while uploading but still it is giving me an error. so please let me know how to handle this error.

Answer (score 0):

`Image. compress(params..)` is asynchronous function which returns a promise, and **should not be executed inside JSX**.

More about React and Asynchronous programming -  https://medium.com/capbase-engineering/asynchronous-functional-programming-using-react-hooks-e51a748e6869

Comment: then how can I make it possible, please explain....

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of this package, you are not using `await` in front of `Image.compress` as Image.compress is returning a promise

You should compress image into `useEffect` and use `useState` for compressed image uri and then you can use it in JSX `Image` component, you can use example code from code

**Note:** don't forget to use the latest version of https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-compressor